# How to find out the signature of a Google ML Cloud model version

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm looking for a way to figure out the signature, the inputs and outputs, of a model version running on Google ML Cloud.
None of the available Google ML REST APIs allows me to see the inputs a model version expects and its outputs.

Answer (score 0):

We do not yet support this from the API. However, you can use `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model` locally to view the signature(s) of a TensorFlow model.